# how to make my LSTM model predict after training

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, prediction

I'm a begginer at ML and I'm using an LSTM model to forcast a future value of a column I think i succeded in training my model but I'm strugling to make my model predict the future values 
my dataset is like this:
   c0            c1         c2        c3          c4          c5
 0.953202     0.998825   0.943329   0.762738    0.046798      0.0
....
I trained my model to predict the values of c5 based on the the other columns

```py
# split into train and test sets
values = reframed.values
n_train_hours = 24*24
train = values[:n_train_hours, :]
test = values[n_train_hours:, :]

# split into input and outputs
train_X, train_y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
test_X, test_y = test[:, :-1], test[:, -1]
# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape, try1.shape)

# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
# fit network
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=50, batch_size=72, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)

# make a prediction
      ???
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your model to predict with:

```
print(model.predict('''your sample'''))
```

This will print the predicted labels.

Answer (score 0):

**To see predictions:**

```
model.predict(test_X)
```

**To calculate acurracy and loss for test data:**

```
model.evaluate(test_X,test_Y)
```

You can find everythin about model methods in https://keras.io/models/model/